# Servlet: Handling many optional parameters

Tags: java, servlets, parameters

Just wondering if there is a more elegant or standard way to handle the optional parameters or if you have to check if every one is null.  I have 10+ optional parameters so it is getting somewhat ugly.

Ideally I would like something like the bash command: `getopts`.

```
public class MapImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ... constructor and other methods ...
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
        if(request.getParameter("boarderSize") != null){
            double boarderSize = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("boarderSize");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("boarderThickness") != null){
            double boarderThickness = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("boarderThickness");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("boarderColor") != null){
            double boarderColor = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("boarderColor");
        }
        ... do stuff with the parameters ...
    }
    ... other methods ...
}
```

Comment: Don't declare the variable inside your if statement, it won't be available to other scopes.

Comment: @Marcelo, sorry about that.  Normally would not do that, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a utility like this

```
public class MapImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
//... constructor and other methods ...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // OPTIONAL PARAMETERS
     boarderSize = ParamUtil.getDoubleValue(request,"boarderSize", defaultValue);

     boarderThickness = ParamUtil.getDoubleValue(request, "boarderThickness", defaultValue);

     boarderColor = ParamUtil.getDoubleValue(request,"boarderColor" , defaultValue);
     //... do stuff with the parameters ...
}

}
public class ParamUtil
{
public static double getDoubleValue(ServletRequest request, String paramName, double defaultValue)
{
     if(request.getParameter(paramName) != null){
        return Double.valueOf(request.getParameter(paramName));
    } else{
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I thought that there would already be something made like this already in the servlet but I guess that it is easy to make my own.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you looking for: [ServletRequest#getParameterMap](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29)?

Comment: Incase you are stuck on an old WAS or something, getParameterMap is in JEE 5.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I have used Apache beanutils to pull information from request parameter map. BeanUtils provides a nice interface that hides all this information from you ...

```
MyJavaBean mjb = new MyJavaBean();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(mjb, request.getParameterMap());

.... 
// do stuff with mjb properties
logger.debug(mjb.getBorderThickness());
logger.debug(mjb.getBorderSize());
// etc
```

A little extra work setting up the javabean but easy to use going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing this from scratch I suggest you go with a framework like Spring MVC or Struts.  These frameworks capture the input and provide you with a ready to use bean with all the form data.