# How is it possible to specify servlet input data via URL: like http://example.com/servlet/ReverseServlet "Reverse Me"

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

From [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

> If your ReverseServlet is located at
>   http://example.com/servlet/ReverseServlet, then when you run the
>   Reverse program using
>
> `http://example.com/servlet/ReverseServlet "Reverse Me"`

I am confused about the last line - how is it possible to pass "Reverse Me" into servlet and how is this available within servlet?

1) When a `<form action="MyServlet">` within an html-form, I then do `String userInputIntoFormControl = request.getParameter("textBoxName")` within my Servlet, but what to do here within my Servlet?

2) why such a strange form of passing information (args/params) into servlet is needed and when is it practically used?

Comment: In HTTP GET scenario you can pass the parameter in this way: http://example.com/servlet/ReverseServlet?parameterName=parameterValue. You can check this article in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335759/servlet-handling-many-optional-parameters